JPackaged App Start MSI Installer and then System.exit()
I have a JPackaged JavaFX app that reads a github repo's releases to retrieve updates. When an update it found, it downloads the new .msi file and runs it. However, if I run the MSI without exiting the application completely (Such as Platform.exit()) the installer doesn't work properly, as there is an application running in the directory that it's trying to install to. I am FORCED to use System.exit() to close the app.
The further issue with that is that I have tried using both Runtime.exec() and ProcessBuilder, but both of those get shut down when the app is closed via System.exit().
How do I run a task/process (msiexec) from a Java app, and then close the Java app with System.exit(), without ending the external process?

Which version of jpackage are you using? There was a regression in version 21.0.2 where exiting the Java process also kills any forked child processes. Looks like it's fixed in version 23, though there are some backports to 22.0.1 and 21.0.4-oracle (other vendors probably also have the backport for 21.0.4). Of course, none of those versions are released yet. You could instead try an older version of jpackage.

@Slaw I'm using the Azul OpenJDK 17 + FX bundle. Sounds to me like I may need to increment to 21 or 23 then?

@Slaw just confirmed this, rolled back 17.0.10 to 17.07 and it is no longer an issue.

This is a duplicate, I think the bug was backported to 17. You only need to run jpackage of an older 17/21 release to avoid it

Yes, the bug report also says the issue affects 17.0.10, meaning the regression was backported. Looks like the fix will be backported to 17.0.12 (not released yet). For now, you'll have to use an older version of 17 or 21 for jpackage. Also see this comment by DuncG.

From Slaw's comment:
There was a regression in version 21.0.2 where exiting the Java process also kills any forked child processes. Looks like it's fixed in version 23, though there are some backports to 22.0.1 and 21.0.4-oracle (other vendors probably also have the backport for 21.0.4). Of course, none of those versions are released yet. You could instead try an older version of jpackage.
I confirmed that the issue resided in jpackage itself, and rolling back to 17.0.7 fixed my problem.
